# JSVGCanvas svg is blurry

Tags: java, swing, svg, batik

I have pretty much copy pasted the code from [http://people.apache.org/~clay/batik/svgcanvas.html](http://people.apache.org/%7Eclay/batik/svgcanvas.html)
but the svg that is outputing is blurry. I have used both a fontawesome and a material ui svg but both were blurry. What am i doing wrong? Here is my code:

```java
public class GUI extends JFrame{
    public void init(){
        initFrame();
        CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(cl);
        panel.add(createHome(), "HOME");
        panel.setBackground(new Color(200, 0, 50));
        cl.show(panel, "HOME");

        add(panel);
        setSize(1280, 720);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createHome(){
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        {
            JPanel d = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            d.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
            p.add(d, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

            JSVGCanvas svg = new JSVGCanvas();
            d.setSize(this.getWidth(), 50);
            d.add(svg);

            String s = new File("images/userIcon3.svg").toURI().toString();
            svg.setMySize(new Dimension(200, 200));
            svg.setURI(s);
        }

        p.setBackground(new Color(0, 50, 200));
        p.setSize(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        return p;
    }

    private void initFrame(){
        int width = 1280, height = 720;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int swidth = screenSize.width, sheight = screenSize.height;

        setTitle("Travelling Agency");
        setLocation((swidth - width) / 2, (sheight - height) / 2); //Position it in the center
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

[image: Blurry svg]

Comment: You need to turn on antialiasing

Comment: System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","on");
System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true"); in the main method

Comment: Didn't do the trick for me... @JustanotherJavaprogrammer

Comment: Found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70764493/java-applications-are-not-rendered-properly-on-my-system

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer actually it did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with the help from another question of mine ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70764493/14119438)) I have come to this conclusion. 
Due to the fact that I am working on a laptop with 14 inch screen, Windows has a recommendation for scaling my screen to 125% to improve readability. 
So with the help from this answer ([here](https://superuser.com/a/1207925/1660447)) I've set the **"High DPI scaling override"** to **"System"** for my java.exe. 
But even though it fixed how the svg is displayed, it had problems with the text. So I added the System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","on");
System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
that @JustanotherJavaprogrammer mentioned in the comments and now everything seems to be fixed.