# Java applications are not rendered properly on my system

Tags: java, graphics, system

Continuing from my previous question: ([JSVGCanvas svg is blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70760607/jsvgcanvas-svg-is-blurry)),
I remembered that all of the java applications that I have on my laptop have the same problem of text/fonts/icons not rendering correctly. This has happened ONLY in my java applications. Here is a screenshot of my MySQL Workbench: [image: image1]

At first glance it might seem ok, but looking closer you'll see the almost pixelated text and icons. I also had somewhat of the same problem with Xilinx's Vivado IDE. Although it wasn't that bad like MySQL, the drawn schematics were awful. My system is running on a Ryzen 3800U with Vega 8 Graphics with Windows 10->11 (Had the same problem with both 10 and 11). Can anyone help, or am trying to find a needle in a haystack?

Comment: Might be related to the systems DPI - may be have a look at [goggle](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=java+dpi+scaling&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Absolute legend!!!! Thanks a lot! You saved me from a big headache.

Comment: Good luck with getting it fixed 

Comment: I answered both my previous and this question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/70760607/14119438